# ASGI Framework Lifespan error, continuing without Lifespan support

Tags: django, quart

After creating a project with django, and auditing the code via chrome audit, it shows

> Does not use HTTP/2 for all of its resources 2 requests not served via
>   HTTP/2

to fix this error I followed this tutorial

https://medium.com/python-pandemonium/how-to-serve-http-2-using-python-5e5bbd1e7ff1

and when using the code specified for quart

```
import ssl

from quart import make_response, Quart, render_template, url_for

app = Quart(__name__)

@app.route('/')
async def index():
    result = await render_template('index.html')
    response = await make_response(result)
    response.push_promises.update([
        url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap.min.css'),
        url_for('static', filename='js/bootstrap.min.js'),
        url_for('static', filename='js/jquery.min.js'),
    ])
    return response


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context(
        ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH,
    )
    ssl_context.options |= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1 | ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1
    ssl_context.set_ciphers('ECDHE+AESGCM')
    ssl_context.load_cert_chain(
        certfile='cert.pem', keyfile='key.pem',
    )
    ssl_context.set_alpn_protocols(['h2', 'http/1.1'])
    app.run(host='localhost', port=5000, ssl=ssl_context)
```

I get

> /home/avin/Documents/projects/portfolio/portfolio_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/quart/app.py:1320:
>   UserWarning: Additional arguments, ssl, are not yet supported
>   "Additional arguments, {}, are not yet
>   supported".format(','.join(kwargs.keys())), Running on
>   https://localhost:5000 (CTRL + C to quit) [2019-11-06 18:30:18,586]
>   ASGI Framework Lifespan error, continuing without Lifespan support

and also I cant load the webpage via https://localhost:5000

Answer (score 3):

> ASGI Framework Lifespan error, continuing without Lifespan support

Is really just a warning, it notes that Django does not yet support the lifespan part of the ASGI specification. Which won't cause you any issues (given the snippet).

The article you've referenced is outdated, [this is an updated version](https://pgjones.dev/blog/http-1-2-3-2019/). To make it work for your your snippet just change the `if` statement to this (below) and it should work, (although the updated article shows a better way)

```
...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(
        host='localhost', port=5000, certfile='cert.pem', keyfile='key.pem'
    )
```